# client feature:install fcrepo-service-activemq

Tags: activemq-classic, ubuntu-20.04, apache-karaf, apache-karaf-feature

I'm trying to Install Karaf Features on Ubuntu 20.04 using the code below.

```
/opt/karaf/bin/client feature:install fcrepo-service-activemq
```

And I am getting the message error below:

```
Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=fcrepo-service-activemq; type=karaf.feature; version="[5.0.0,5.0.0]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=fcrepo-service-activemq)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=5.0.0)(version<=5.0.0))" [caused by: Unable to resolve fcrepo-service-activemq/5.0.0: missing requirement [fcrepo-service-activemq/5.0.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=activemq-camel; type=karaf.feature; version="[5.14.0,6.0.0)" [caused by: Unable to resolve activemq-camel/5.15.11: missing requirement [activemq-camel/5.15.11] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.apache.activemq.activemq-camel; type=osgi.bundle; version="[5.15.11,5.15.11]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.activemq.activemq-camel/5.15.11: missing requirement [org.apache.activemq.activemq-camel/5.15.11] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.jms.connection)(version>=4.0.0)(!(version>=6.0.0)))"]]]
```

What should I do to install this feature successfully without any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Servus,

Installation notes created by my predecessor show that before command

*features:install*

I should add a repository, that is

*features:addurl*

which adds a *symbolic* repository based on a file stored at

.../etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg

Maybe this is the issue here.